# How would multiple alien races inhabit a planet like Coruscant?

Tags: planets, aliens

I was curious how a planet like Coruscant from the movie Star Wars would work in real life, hundreads of different sapient alien species inhabiting one planet. Let's assume now they all come from planets like Earth with an atmosphere consisting mostly of nitrogen and oxygen with traces of water, carbon dioxide. The gravity of their homeworlds they originate from does vary between 38% of Earth's gravity to 180%. Would the aliens to be able to eat the same food grown on the planet? Would it be possible for the aliens to live peacefully? What type of government could this planet have to maintain peace? We can refer to the planet as "Elysium"

Some details about Elysium

- 0.235 (M⊕)
- 0.60 G
- 7951 km

Comment: I see three questions here, two of which are about peace. I consider "can there be peace" dependent on the needs of your story, both both are opinion-based. That leaves just the question about consuming food, [which has been asked before](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/47787/6986). You may want to rethink your topics of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, as long as they all breathe the same air and aren't physiologically crippled by the gravity (all things you covered) then there is no problem.

As for what they eat...you can buy darn near anything to eat in New York City, even though no food grows there. Since Coruscant is pretty much covered in a city, its a good bet that the food grows somewhere else and is shipped in.

Finally, there are people from every nation on earth living in New York. In fact, there are 3 million out of 8 million total born in other countries. Many of them are still citizens of those other countries. Yet New York, despite having been this way for centuries now, isn't particularly volatile or dangerous compared to other cities, despite all the different people living cheek-by-jowl.