# If we traveled back to the Triassic era could we survive?

Tags: alternate-history, technological-development

If we could travel back to Triassic era and settle there with modern technology, how well could we survive? For example, if there was an alien invasion and we traveled back in time to the triassic era to be ready against alien invasion, could we surive until that time?

So its like this there is something called time crystal that appears every quantilion year or so per universe so that crystal spawned in earth and aliens detected  it and so the invastion so the people of the earth made a machine size as biggest stadiums and the machine can be used three times after the crytal get self destroyed it self along the machine and by traveling back in time they have created a new timeline so human extinct  in original timeline but in new time line human can do whatever the hack they want.

Humans can travel solar system but not outside  it   to Venus to Uranus colonizing is not so great(only hundread or so can live there)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. I'm afraid that at the moment your question is too broad to be answered here.Could you edit your question to narrow it down? If you need any more help you can take the tour or visit the help centre or ask someone.

Comment: This can be interpreted a couple of different ways. Please add some more to your question so that we can figure out what you really want. And it would be nice to know a couple of things you think might happen.

Comment: Setting up shop 248 MA years ago with today's technology? Consider we went from stone tools and hunter-gatherer existence to today in 5000 years of recorded history, and try extrapolating another thousand years, much less million. After 200 million years we will be in the post-post-post human era.

Comment: Hi swswsws, and welcome to the site. We get questions every now and then on how changing some aspect up to a few hundred years ago would affect the modern day, and consider *those* to be too broad because the implications would already be huge. Your question is many orders of magnitude larger. Sorry, but there is just no reasonable way to answer this; the kind of change you are asking about can essentially be considered unbounded magic, in that the answer can be almost literally whatever you want it to be.

Comment: @Thucydides  Or we would have stripped the Earth's resources and destroyed ourselves given that we have managed to nearly cause runaway global warming in the last 200 years.

Comment: @Bellerophon There was far less fossil fuels back then, which might actually work in the favor of the protagonists in this case.

Comment: Just a quick reminder: a question that is put on hold can be reopened after some edits, if the question fits the standards of the site after the edits. Maybe you could focus on a single aspect and rethink the tme-scale. Some thoughts of yours about possible outcomes would be nice too. Maybe something like "I thought about our energy production: if there is not so much fossil fuels we would have had clean energy much faster which in turn leads to [stuff] and would allow me [twist] i my story."

Comment: O.o shady folks suspending a question again?! jk :p. Anyway. I don't think the premise of the question is _too broad_ as OP is just asking if humans could **survive** until modern time, starting from the Triassic Period, with modern technology. While I do agree that the answers could go volumes upon volumes if they get into intricate details, but I think the basics of **survival of human race, with modern technology, from Triassic to now/Holocene** can be easily covered in a 5 - 8 paragraph answer. Personally, I find the question rather interesting, (if only paradoxical) and would write for it

Comment: This needs to explain more about how the travel actually works.  How many people can go back?  How much stuff?  One time?  Or ongoing?  Can they communicate with the future?  How are paradoxes handled?  Do they have to be able to rebuild civilization?  To what time?  The same future moment from which they left?

Comment: Do i need  to explain  everything?

Comment: @swswsws Probably. Try to add information about some of the questions raised in the comments at a time then we can help you step by step. If you are unsure about some aspects you can write @ + username and ask the person to help you, or you can go to the chat and ask for help. After some edits your question can be reopened. Try to start with some aspects you can think of. I think "How many people can go back?" and "Can they communicate with the future?" are good starting points. There is always a chance to ignore things by saying "I handwave [stuff]", which means "I ignore it because magic!"

Comment: You need to explain a few things, I agree, but not _everything_ Brythan mentioned. For example, you need to mention a) how many people get to go back. b) how much technology (as in, what inventions) do they get to take back? Can they transport whole metal refineries level buildings with them or just small things like guns, phones etc? c) Can they go to any future time as they want or do they stick to the period they travel to (aka Triassic)? That's all. You don't need to explain how time travel paradoxes etc are handled as they are irrelevant to the core of the question which is about survival

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The triassic period ended with the (appropriately named) [end-Triassic extinction](https://www.britannica.com/science/end-Triassic-extinction) which resulted in the extinction of approximately 76% of all marine and terrestrial species. So it's possibly that your time travelers didn't make it past that barrier at all.

However, one theory is that this period of extinction was not a sudden event but a result of climate change due to volcanism from the rift of the continent of Pangea over 40,000 to 620,000 years. Humans are nothing if not adaptable so chances are we would survive.

So, you have humans in a period where most species are under extreme pressure from climate change AND under extreme pressure from a new apex predator (us). I would imagine that the Triassic period would begin with far less genetic diversity than it did.  This, of course, has huge ramifications on which species evolve. For example, the first mammals evolved in the late Triassic period. Would a dominate human technological society accidentally drive them to extinction as well?  The cascading effect of that over the next 200 million years would be unimaginable.

My answer to the question: when the "aliens" invasion arrives in the modern era humans–assuming we still exist–would have 200 million years of evolution on a world where many common creatures (including, possibly, the entire class of Mammalia) may have never even evolved. Earth would be, I think, totally unrecognizable.

Comment: I think it's worth comparing to this [Simba's answer to Would humans be able to derive nutrition from foodstuffs found on alien planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/47870/29) which actually *specifically discusses* Earth's Triassic period.

Comment: All of a sudden I'm picturing a world where the end-Triassic extinction was caused by humans, in which case everything would turn out the way it did the first time (paradox resolved!).  Sure, blame everything on us.

Comment: The Triassic lasted for 20.9 million years. It should be easy to avoid either extinctions. Either by preparing for the end-Triassic event or time travelling around it. Twenty million years is plenty of time to prepare. I like the idea of having 200 million years head start on the alien invaders.