# What hardships would humans face colonizing a nearby habitable world

Tags: science-fiction, space-colonization, far-future

My story involves a groups of colonists from a near post-apocalyptic Earth settling on a nearby, newly discovered habitable world, each colony separated and unknown to the others initially. Throughout the years, these colonists populate the planet and expand their colonies eventually discovering each other. But not before they have to deal with the challenges of living on a new world.

My first question is this, in detail, **Realistically, what would be the initial hardships and challenges they would face landing and settling on this uninhabited new world in the order of survival.**

Comment: Even just that one question is still too broad.

Comment: Good edit, but "survival, growth and technology" still looks like three distinct fields, and "initial and long-term" make this a total of 6 categories, or hidden questions. You might be interested in existing questions such as [Would humans be able to derive nutrition from foodstuffs found on alien planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/47787/would-humans-be-able-to-derive-nutrition-from-foodstuffs-found-on-alien-planets) to see how to ask these types of questions.

Comment: I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Could you direct me to the chat room where I can get opinions on brainstorm idea? I heard such one existed.

Comment: @NoahRogers [Here is the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor). Our main chat room is called the *Factory Floor*. You need 20 reputation though. You can get 2 rep for suggesting an edit to a post, such as fixing typos. You get 5 rep for an upvote to on of your questions. 10 rep for an upvote on one of your answers. And 2 rep for accepting an answer. 15 if an answer of yours is accepted. Getting to 20 shouldn't take too long if you participate a bit.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question by the way. Keep it up, I hope you stick around! Have fun on the site.

Comment: I will admit first I was a little upset by the votes to hold my questions and the policy concerning them. But now I understand so thank you.

Comment: Initial and long term hardships covers a very long timescale. It feels like you're wanting us to outline your story for you. If you restricted the scope of your question further to just the initial hardships I think it would be specific enough to be opened.

Comment: I've cast the fifth and final reopen vote, but I agree with @sphennings that narrowing it down to one of those categories would still be an improvement.

Comment: That is a BIG question, we have a definition, for questions that are Too-Broad, we ask a simple question "could I write a book about this?" I feel this question does rate a full book answer, or several.

Comment: You may want to include what technologies available to them. If they are so advanced that they can terraform the planet in 1 day, then hostile environment will be non-issue to them.

Comment: and could you describe this planet? Colonizing a life-barren planet will be very different than colonizing a planet with a lot of macro life-forms

Comment: It's quite Earth like with similar year cycles and ecosystems. The planets orbit is more ovalish and circular moving from the inner and outer habitable zones of the star. The planets "seasons" are rather simple. Hot summer and cold winter planet wide with the exception of regions around the equator. So to answer your question, the planet is quite Earth like, but due to it's strange orbit, it has wet and dry spells, very hot and very cold times. Yes there are a vast array of life forms on this planet. Everything from insects to large predators of different kinds. Some friendly and many hostile

Comment: This comment identifying what life-forms are on the planet when the 1st colonists arrive is a crucial aspect to defining the initial hardships.  GOOD LUCK with your story - I think you've got a real bundle of fun ahead!

Comment: A major plot hole is that signals and communications systems on such advanced colonization craft would make all colonies well aware of each other long before they reach the nearby planet. Each ship would have its sensors damaged in a nearly identical way from the very beginning of their journey in order for them to be unaware of each other - something very dangerous for a journey through space. Even so, I see such people quickly repairing any such damage enroute, and then discovering and communicating with each other before landing.

Comment: My previous comment may well play into hardships - particularly if the groups are or become enemies while traveling through space, and may seed societal drama well before trying to survive on a new planet. There may also be the case that one or two ships are not, or will not, communicate with others, so there is quite a surprise after landing for one or two ships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to address the spirt of your question I will make some assumptions please correct me if I’m wrong. I will assume that habitable means more or less earth like, but with different surface features, a relatively benign earth life friendly biosphere where all or most life forms are simply inedible but non-toxic. The technology and distance are such that a trip can be made in less than a year and 10,000 colonists can be sent. I will assume near future.

**Survival**
The initial difficulty would be to introduce and establish viable numbers of earth species of plant and animal. This might be difficult even on a habitable world because the local flora and fauna would be well adapted to live there and even if not poisonous would at best be highly invasive. This should be possible but might not be easy and it would be essential to produce food.

**Technological development**
A second difficulty would be the danger of loss of technical capability. They might arrive with high tech kit but it would all be subject to damage and might be difficult or impossible to repair. There is only so much repair capability that you can bring and that is itself open to damage and degradation.

So a second aim would be to build basic infrastructure to help provide what was needed, But I doubt they could actually create enough infrastructure quickly enough to support their original level of technology because modern technology includes so many interrelated complex and hard to manufacture parts. So they would eventually loose capability and would start to struggle to rebuild equipment. As an example when they run out of spares and improvisations, any computer screen that got cracked or bulldozer engine ring that broke would put that piece of kit permanently out of operation.

So they will struggle to establish themselves technologically. With luck and provided they still had access to the information necessary to build the technology they once had, they should slowly reacquire it although it might take centuries.

As an example before you can build your first microchip to help return your computer technology you need a vast array of other technologies, each of which themselves require even more technologies, so to mention just a few you would need zone refining of silicon which itself would need vacuum technology which itself would need electrical technology etc.

**Social development**
Eventually these separate colonies would run into one another probably in search of resources (although it is very hard to believe that so many separate colonise could be established on the same world in the high tech stage without being aware of the presence of some or all of the others).

The mega corporations would be long forgotten and the merits of environmental friendly or not outlooks would be overtaken by events on the ground and the struggle to survive.

The religious cult might well retain its beliefs but naturalistic and harmonist views would probably be amended by the need to survive. The militaristic and isolationist societies’ viewpoint would lose a lot of meaning and potency in a world where the only enemy was nature. By the time other groups were encountered the societies may well have moved on or at least the original ideology might be much weaker.

The various different forms of initial government and world view would in all likelihood evolve rapidly and many changes might make the groups completely unrecognisable after a few decades. Different sub groups might take control depending on circumstances. Mini revolutions and revolts could over throw the historical outlook.

**Final out come**
At the point of contact I would think the bonds of humanity and a common enemy (the alien environment) would outweigh any vestige of their original purpose / outlook. In such survival situations many things originally intended would simply be forgotten or lost. It is also possible that the ingroup out group  type thinking would take hold and fighting would break out.

In fact eventually there would be cause for much fighting, probably over resources or priorities, (or women) but it is impossible to say what would happen eventually as there are too many variables and too much time would have passed. Probably geographical location would play a bigger role than the original colonies ideology.

Comment: np - you might be interested in Proxima by Stephen Baxter https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17983396-proxima this has a vaguely similar story line with multiple colonies, The ending is very unusual as the last apargraph is in latin. I'm just off to the latin SE to get it translated

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: I'm referencing groups from an earlier version of the question.*

Welcome to Worldbuilding SE. Unfortunately your question looks much too broad. All of these colonies could put their *interests* ahead of their *ideology* and fight any rival. That's how the Alpha Centauri game is set up.

- A, the first B, C, and E could become expansionist in search of economic advantage, raw materials, and captive markets.
- D and F could become expansionist to spread their ideology, and to "save the oppressed workers" elsewhere.
- G could become expansionist to eliminate rivals.
- If you look at recent events in [Myanmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohingya_persecution_in_Myanmar_(2016%E2%80%93present)), or the breakup of [British India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_India), even your second Colony B could become quite violent.

---

**Follow-Up:** The question changed. So how does the situation you describe differ from the Spaniards meeting the Incas, or the Romans meeting the Indians?

- I would expect that all colonies have **maps** from orbital surveys, accurate as of the date of the last landing of their group (or even slightly later, if they left sats to update the maps). There will be no surprise that there is a mountain range behind the desert, and a coast behind that. Exploration teams might be surprised that another colony has built a port city at a river mouth, but they would know that the river mouth is a good place for a port city.
- The last team will know the location of **all** previous sites. A shuttle is large enough to detect from orbit, and so is a farming village. The next-to-last team might be surprised about the position of the last colony, but not vice versa.
- The teams will try to balance their colony site between immediate needs (good farming) and long-term needs (raw materials, hydropower, and so on). Afterwards there might be a *race to the mining sites.* Settlements expand to stake their claim. Read up on the [Fashoda Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fashoda_Incident).
- The teams might have databases (or printed books, if they fear that their computers break down) to outline a direct path from blacksmiths to modern industry. There is an entire genre of science fiction books where a hero uplifts a world with the aid of such data, usually without the complication of separate factions.

Comment: If the question is too broad, you should not answer it and rather flag and wait for clarification.

Comment: I dispute that it is too broad of a question. Not trying to sound contrary but these three questions I found necessary to ask have been satisfactorily answered given the conditions I listed. I understand that they may not be specific questions but at the stage I am at, I still am in the need for assistance at developing my story and made that a point to say. I was seeking opinions and realistic examples of how such a scenario would play out and I should say these answers have helped a lot. That's all I want to say.

Comment: Also, I want to thank all for your answers and opinions. This has helped me a lot.

Comment: @Vylix, I think I gave a *partial* answer, especially regarding groups that one might assume are inherently peaceful (second B, G).

Comment: @o.m. yep. But I disagree that you answer while the question is *certainly* will be closed for being too broad. As you can see now, your answer is invalidated. Can you update it to answer the current question?

Comment: I disagree that each Colony have to know of the other Colonies location - or even existence.  OP has stated Post Apocalyptic.  It's pretty easy to posit a series of unmanned Colony vessels with colonists in hibernation of somekind.  With an Automated landing and disembarkation.  It would even be a decent plot line to have 1 or 2 colonies arrive but fail to disembark successfully.  All Colonies could be sent out in roughly the same timeframe - and have little to no knowledge of any other efforts to colonise. - Post Apocalyptic scenarios very commonly have serious communication issues.

Comment: That is true and thats really what I was leaning on. The plot unfolds with the different colonies ending up on the same world to be a major coincidence. But that coincidence leads to majors problems and conflicts.  And it opens up the possibility for a repeat of the conflicts of Earth on this new world.

Comment: @kiltannen, interstellar travel is *incredibly* difficult as far as we know. Compared to that, mapping is easy. The idea that the ship can *find* a habitable world and travel there, without taking pictures on the way, seems improbable. And if the ship failed/crashed, what are the chances for surviving passengers?

Comment: @o.m. You are right interstallar travel is *incredibly* difficult.  But the OP was looking for a way to legitmately have up to 9 colonies on the planet with no awareness of each other.  They also were careful to point out the "apocalypse" that destroyed civilisation happened b4 departure. It's not too much of a stretch that automated colony ships were built b4 or during the crash and that the capabilities were very basic. Also that the ship didn't find the new world that was b4 crash. Think of some of the challenges in the TV show "the 100" - there are ways to make what the OP wanted possible.

Comment: @kiltannen, I pointed out that some things are just improbable. Like saying that someone can build an aircraft carrier but not a compass on the bridge. Orbital recon is well-known tech. The interstellar drive is incredibly difficult.

Answer (score 2):

HUGE question, but lets look at the "threes of survival"; i.e. a human can survive "three minutes without air, three hours without shelter, three days without water and three weeks without food" now that's a mix of some best and worst cases but it's a working model we can go from.

So first priority is the atmosphere A. "move in ready", an exact duplicate of Earth that presents no issues, B. "reno ready", close enough to Earth to set up camp and make some improvements like breeding plants that extract excess sulfates, at levels that aren't toxic but are unpleasant C. "bare land", oh look a soup of Ammonia, Methane, Carbon Monoxide and Fluorine time to break out the atmosphere reprocessors. Between the "reno" and "bare" is a sliding scale of progressive nastiness depending where you are on that scale you need equipment etc... ranging from nothing special to rules about exposure times to full-blown hermetically sealed shelters for sleeping and space suits for any outdoor working parties. Special case is hard vacuum but I don't see that being a colonisation target.

Second you need to be protected from the elements, that could mean cold, heat, rain, wind or even meteor swarms. Extreme cold and heat are probably less of an issue than they can be for planetary explorers on Earth, space ships and travelers will, of a necessity, have a lot more insulation and climate control than your average tramper because space is harder to keep a healthy temperature in than atmosphere. Rain is always problematic, due to increased heat loss and degradation of footing and visibility, there's not that much you can do except endure it and try to keep dry where possible to prevent skin problems. Unusual effects may have to be taken into account in light of acidic atmosphere etc... Wind can potentially be lethally strong on an exoplanet, not like a tornado where a weather event might kill you but the basic everyday wind could actually kill you from shear impact force, there are just some situations that you can't know about until you arrive and can't do anything about once you do. Protecting people from the environment is similar to protecting them from a toxic atmosphere and runs to the same extremes of don't go outside unprotected. You also need to protect equipment in similar ways.

Water is probably not that big of a problem if you have good shelter and the planet has a hydrological cycle, one of the things that humans have proven to excel at is sourcing water and building technologies that source water.

Food could be the biggest challenge to the longterm survival of a colony, this has been true on Earth in virgin territory and will probably be just as true outside our own biosphere, only more so. There are two real options, one is to bring a large stockpile, and a gene lab and hope you can solve any problems arising, the other is a large stockpile and a full hydroponics set up to grow all the food you need indefinitely, this may or may not be a practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

Wow,  Some very big questions here.  Certainly you are setting up for huge conflict once they do discover each other!

I don't think I can answer all of your question, but I'll have a crack at laying out some of the challenges when they 1st set up the colonies.

1. There are some basic challenges with colonizing another planet - and the 1st assumption is does it already have life on it?
2. I'm assuming yes - because if not it's WAY too hard a challenge to get colonies off the ground well enough to survive if they are tech limited in the way you describe.
3. SO with life already there - there are likely to be be critters and even plants that will be deadly.
4. This worlds equivalent of Lions & Tigers.  They might have 6 legs and teeth like a Sabre Tooth, or they might have poison like a Snake or spider.  They could be tiny or large - but they will be there and they will be deadly.
5. Even some of the normally not deadly animals might go through a phase change of some kind - and turn deadly overnight - either a permanent change - or a temporary one.
6. There could easily be a mineral in the ground that is slowly toxic in subtle ways - and that might be restricted to certain areas - so you could easily have it affect just one of some of your colonies.  It could cause unexpected mutations, the simplest one that would cause huge social upheaval but not be obvious until quite a ways down the road is if it were to affect the Birth rate between Male and Female.   It could have an affect as simple as making all female (or male whichever way you wanted to play that) Zygotes split into a twin. Or even triplets.  That would force quite radical changes in certain of your societies.
7. Another way a mineral could have severe toxicity but not be noticed, is if it interacted with the brain in a way to cause Prions to fold - but only after 3 decades of exposure.So you would end up with one of your colonies having pretty much their whole population developing Mad Cows disease, after they turn 30.  So they can have kids - the colony could survive, but huge challenges.  And not figured out until a LOONG time has passed.
8. Another subtle effect could be to enhance PSI talents, so Telekinesis, Telepathy, Precognition, Super Empathy, and other kinds of PSI talents all could be useful plot elements, and 1 or 2 colonies getting these at the exclusion of the others is a good conflict point.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas for developing your story lines with some unique quirks...

Comment: Thank you. And trust me, this does help. Do you think though that if the colonists managed to start researching some kind of cure or discovering such diseases early on, they could find a way to counter it?

Comment: They way I posited things, the easiest cure would be to move away from from the source of toxicity.  Of course - if you made there be a general toxicity over the whole planet that would be quite a problem.  I did not suggest a general poisen across the whole planet affecting all colonies equally - because your original post said the world was habitable.

Comment: Of Course - moving away from the source of the toxicity after you've established a colony for 30+ years will be hugely cost prohibitive.  Some decent plot points in that!  Some further decent plot points in potential territory conflict with other colonies in the new, safe, destination.

Comment: Hmmm. Something to think about. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that one can find a 'class M' planet, one that approximates the Earth in climate with a considerable water presence, plus an oxygen/nitrogen atmosphere and a strong magnetic field to keep solar wind from blowing that atmosphere away, there is still the immediate challenge of food.

First order of business is survival. Feeding a space ship's crew during travel is difficult enough, without also having to transport enough food to keep the settlers supplied for any length of time once they arrive.

Does that planet have life on it?

And is that life edible? It would be unfortunate to arrive at that planet, only to find that the local plants had cyanide in their sap.

Is that life hostile? Would the indigenous life regard humans to be a tasty snack? Are there microbes or parasites that humans would have no natural defense against? The human body has considerable defenses... against intruders found on earth.

Can one introduce earth plants to produce food? And what are the consequences of doing that?

Keep in mind that life on earth has evolved to be optimal for the earth's climate and resources. Life on another planet will have evolved to be optimal for different conditions, and may function in a very different manner. It may well be inedible, and intolerant of foreign intruders: humans, or the plantlife they bring along to cultivate for food.

Answer (score 0):

Your question overlooks a few things. If you're sending colonists to a world then you also send surveying equipment so they know the best sites before landing and committing themselves. In other words the colonists would bring satellites and they would be multirole satellites. They would also be used for communications. 
Even if the satellites fell into disrepair after a couple of generations the first arrivals on each of the colonies would all be aware of the existence of the other groups. This would be *very* important information. So even if the colony's hi-tech kit started to break down over the years then that information would be recorded by more durable means, books or even word of mouth.

I just don't see how the colonies would be ignorant of each other.

Comment: The colonists are unaware of each other for the first number of years. Not centuries. That was an error. They all arrived on different ships.

Comment: But thank you, I didn't even consider the colonists bringing satellites.